# How to identify number near word using regex

Tags: python-3.x

Need to identify numbers near keyword number:, no:, etc..

```
Tried:

import re
matchstring="Sales Quote"
string_lst = ['number:', 'No:','no:','number','No : ']
x=""" Sentence1: Sales Quote number 36886DJ9 is entered
    Sentence2: SALES QUOTE No: 89745DFD is entered
    Sentence3: Sales Quote No : 7964KL is entered
    Sentence4: SALES QUOTE NUMBER:879654DF is entered
    Sentence5: salesquote no: 9874656LD is entered"""

documentnumber= re.findall(r"(?:(?<="+matchstring+ '|'.join(string_lst)+r')) [\w\d-]',x,flags=re.IGNORECASE)
print(documentnumber)

Required soln:36886DJ9,89745DFD,7964KL,879654DF,9874656LD
```

Is there any solution?

Comment: Running `re.search(r'(\d+[a-zA-Z]+)', 'Sentence2: SALES QUOTE No: 89745DFD is entered').group(1)` will return the string `'89745DFD'`. It ignores the predefined keywords and works on a single line, but you can split `x` into lines and use it.

Comment: Using `re.findall(r'(\d+[a-zA-Z]+)', x)` returns what you want, `['36886DJ', '89745DFD', '7964KL', '879654DF', '9874656LD']``. I didn't know `re.findall`, thanks for introducing it to me.

Comment: I need to get for all keyword "No:, No : ,number , NUMBER:, no:

Comment: It should return numbers after keywords in array ['number:', 'No:','no:','number','No : '] and should combine with matchstring="Sales Quote" Eg: Sales Quote No:

Comment: Try `re.findall(r'[no|number|NUMBER|NO] ?:? ?(\d+[a-zA-Z]+)', x)`. Returns the same array: `['36886DJ', '89745DFD', '7964KL', '879654DF', '9874656LD']`. This regex first tries to match one of your keywords, then an optional single space, then an optional single colon and then another optional space. Another way is to add the spaces and colons into the keywords, but it is not the way it is implemented in this regex. You can change it if you like

Comment: My solution for this: documentnumber = re.findall(r'(?:(?<=' + matchstring + ' number )|(?<=' + matchstring + ' No: )|(?<=' + matchstring.title() + ' No: )|(?<=' + matchstring + ' No : )|(?<=' + matchstring.title() + ' No : ))[\w\d-]+',x) print(document_number) retreive all answer but I am using  | "or" . I need to check all ['number:', 'No:','no:','number','No : ']  without "or"

Comment: # string_lst = ['fun', 'dum', 'sun', 'gum']
# x="I love to have fun."
#
# print re.findall(r"(?=("+'|'.join(string_lst)+r"))", x) ----> How to use inside (re.findall(r"(?:(?<="+matchstring+ '|'.join(string_lst)+r')) [\w\d-]',x,flags=re.IGNORECASE))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually your solution is very close. You just need some missing parenthesis and check for optional whitespace:

```py
documentnumber = re.findall(r"(?:(?<="+matchstring + ").*?(?:" + '|'.join(string_lst) + ')\s?)([\w\d-]*)', x, re.IGNORECASE)
```

However this won't match with the last one (9874656LD) because of the missing whitespace between "Sales" and "quote". If you want to build it in the same way than the rest of the pattern, replace the lookbehind by a non capturing group and join words with `\s?`:

```
documentnumber= re.findall(r"(?:(?:" + "\s?".join(matchstring.split()) + ").*?(?:" + '|'.join(string_lst) + ')\s?)([\w\d-]*)', x, re.IGNORECASE)
```

Output:

```
['36886DJ9', '89745DFD', '7964KL', '879654DF', '9874656LD']
```